# NDSolve doesn't work for this simple differential equations

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I try to use NDSolve to do this partial differential equations, but the result is wrong... The source term is a Gaussian pulse as time and an exponential decay with the depth z. The result should be going to some small value at a large time, but it keeps "plat" when it goes to a large time.  thank you!

[image: p1]
[image: p2]
[image: p3]
[image: p4]
[image: p5]
[image: p6]

I copy the code there..thank you...

```
α = 1.5*10^8;
R = 0.95;
σ = 4.25*10^-9;
μ = 6 σ;
Ce0 = 135;
κ = 235;
g = 24.5*10^16;
Imax = 5*10^13;
Cp = 0.244*10^6;
T0 = 300;
L = 1*10^-6;
tend = 100*10^-9;

pde = {Ce0*Te[t, z]*D[Te[t, z], t] == 
         κ*D[Te[t, z], {z, 2}] - g*(Te[t, z] - Tp[t, z]) + 
           (1 - R)*α*(Imax*Exp[-((t - μ)^2/(2*σ^2))] * Exp[(-α)*z]),
        Cp*D[Tp[t, z], t] == g*(Te[t, z] - Tp[t, z])}; 
bc = {Te[0, z] == T0, Tp[0, z] == T0, 
       Derivative[0, 1][Te][t, 0] == 0, 
       Derivative[0, 1][Te][t, L] == 0};     

ss = NDSolve[{pde, bc}, {Te, Tp}, {t, 0, tend}, {z, 0, L}];

Plot[Evaluate[Te[t, 0] /. ss], {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
Plot[Evaluate[Tp[t, 0] /. ss], {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

---

```
dd = NDSolve[{Ce0*Te[t, z]*D[Te[t, z], t] == κ*D[Te[t, z], {z, 2}] + 
             (1 - R)*α*Imax * Exp[-((t - μ)^2/(2*σ^2))] * Exp[(-α)*z],
         Te[0, z] == T0, 
         Derivative[0, 1][Te][t, 0] == 0, 
         Derivative[0, 1][Te][t, L] == 0}, Te, 
       {t, 0, tend}, {z, 0, L}]; 


Plot[Evaluate[Te[t, 0] /. dd], {t, 0, tend}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
Plot[Evaluate[Te[3*10^-8, z] /. dd], {z, 0, L}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, L}, {0, 10000}}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: BTW, you make it difficult for people to help by not posting actual code they can copy-paste into *Mathematica*. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. (Also, you can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I am learning how to post my code...

Comment: Hi, I re-edit the code, can you see it now? THank you!

Comment: I used the menu command Cell > Convert To > InputForm (in *Mathematica*) to make your code more human-readable.  Please check that I didn't mess up the code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, yes, the converted code is correct, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that as we increase the number of "MinPoints" or decrease the number "MaxStepFraction" is a graph that changes and grows temperature.

Partial differential equation has sharp or oscillating features and cannot be handled reliably.

```
α = 1.5*10^8;
R = 0.95;
σ = 4.25*10^-9;
μ = 6*σ;
Ce0 = 135;
κ = 235;
g = 24.5*10^16;
Imax = 5*10^13;
Cp = 0.244*10^6;
T0 = 300;
L = 50*10^-6;
tend = 300*10^-9;
```

and

```
 dd = NDSolve[{Ce0*Te[t, z]*
 D[Te[t, z], t] == κ*
 D[Te[t, z], {z, 2}] + (1 - R)*α*Imax*
 Exp[-((t - μ)^2/(2*σ^2))]*Exp[(-α)*z], 
 Te[0, z] == T0, Derivative[0, 1][Te][t, 0] == 0, 
 Derivative[0, 1][Te][t, L] == 0}, Te, {t, 0, tend}, {z, 0, L}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
 "MinPoints" -> 2000, "MaxPoints" -> 9999}}];
```

and

```
   Plot[Evaluate[
   Te[t, z] /. dd /. 
   z -> {0, 1*10^-6, 3*10^-6, 10*10^-6, 20*10^-6}], {t, 0, tend}, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> {"z=0 μm", "z=1 μm", "z=3 μm", 
   "z=10 μm", "z=20 μm"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {t ["ns"], Te ["10^3"]}, 
   Ticks -> {{#, 10^9 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., 10^-6}, 40] // 
   N, {#, 0.001 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., 10000}, 10] // N}]
```

[image]

or

```
   dd = NDSolve[{Ce0*Te[t, z]*
   D[Te[t, z], t] == κ*
   D[Te[t, z], {z, 2}] + (1 - R)*α*Imax*
   Exp[-((t - μ)^2/(2*σ^2))]*Exp[(-α)*z], 
   Te[0, z] == T0, Derivative[0, 1][Te][t, 0] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1][Te][t, L] == 0}, Te, {t, 0, tend}, {z, 0, L}, 
   MaxStepFraction -> 0.00025];

    Plot[Evaluate[
   Te[t, z] /. dd /. 
   z -> {0, 1*10^-6, 3*10^-6, 10*10^-6, 20*10^-6}], {t, 0, tend}, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLegends -> {"z=0 μm", "z=1 μm", "z=3 μm", 
   "z=10 μm", "z=20 μm"}, 
   AxesLabel -> {t ["ns"], Te ["10^3"]}, 
   Ticks -> {{#, 10^9 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., 10^-6}, 40] // 
   N, {#, 0.001 #} & /@ FindDivisions[{0., 14000}, 10] // N}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Mariusz, Thank you so much for your help, the plot is awesome! I am looking to your idea and learing the minpoint and maxpoint.

Comment: Hi, Mariusz, do you know how to accept the answer, thank you for your help but I cannot find the button to accept your answer. I cannot vote your answer either... It says I don't have enough reputation